# Update table, but make a new updated table?

Tags: php, sql, database

```
$connection=mysql_connect("localhost","root","pass");

mysql_select_db("webdd");

    $a = $_POST['login'];
    $b = $_POST['passe'];
    $c = $_POST['email'];
    $d = $_POST['nom'];
    $e = $_POST['prenom'];
    $f = $_POST['adresse'];
    $g = $_POST['ville'];
    $h = $_POST['tel']; 

mysql_query("UPDATE prestataire SET (login='$a', passe='$b' , email='$c',nom='$d', prenom='$e', adresse='$f', ville='$g', tel='$h' )WHERE login = '$a' )");

mysql_close();

header("location:profile.php");
```

Comment: Provide some details on your problem

Comment: Also, don't use `mysql_*()` functions for any new code. Those functions have been deprecated. Use PDO to interact with MySQL databases instead. In addition, your code is susceptible to SQL Injection attacks. You always want to make sure that any user input is what you expect it to be before inserting into the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code

```
mysql_query("UPDATE prestataire SET (login='$a', passe='$b' , email='$c',nom='$d', prenom='$e', adresse='$f', ville='$g', tel='$h' )WHERE login = '$a' )");
```

try like this

```
$sql = "UPDATE prestataire SET (login='$a', passe='$b' , email='$c',nom='$d', prenom='$e', adresse='$f', ville='$g', tel='$h' )";


$request = mysql_query($sql);
```

better way

```
 $sql = "UPDATE prestataire SET passe='$b' , email='$c',nom='$d', prenom='$e', adresse='$f', ville='$g', tel='$h' WHERE login='$a'";
```

You are mentioing login twice in update and second in `WHERE` - you dont need to mention login two times

if still not then echo your  `$sql`

P.s DUn use mysql it is deprecated

Comment: if answer help you then accept the answer if you want more help then try and post here your echo result